# Why QThreadData::current use a static variable?

Tags: c++, qt

When reading Qt source code I feel confused about the following [code](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/thread/qthread.cpp?h=v5.12.6):

```cpp
// No threads: so we can just use static variables
static QThreadData *data = 0;

QThreadData *QThreadData::current(bool createIfNecessary)
{
    if (!data && createIfNecessary) {
        data = new QThreadData;
        data->thread = new QAdoptedThread(data);
        data->threadId.store(Qt::HANDLE(data->thread));
        data->deref();
        data->isAdopted = true;
        if (!QCoreApplicationPrivate::theMainThread)
            QCoreApplicationPrivate::theMainThread = data->thread.load();
    }
    return data;
}
```

and its's usage in [QObject::moveToThread](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/kernel/qobject.cpp?h=v5.12.6)

```cpp
QThreadData *currentData = QThreadData::current();
QThreadData *targetData = targetThread ? QThreadData::get2(targetThread) : nullptr;
if (d->threadData->thread == 0 && currentData == targetData) {
    // one exception to the rule: we allow moving objects with no thread affinity to the current thread
   currentData = d->threadData;
}
```

I think`QThreadData::current()`should return different values when called from different thread, but how this can be achieved in the fact of using a static/global data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking at the wrong place - you're in the else branch of `#if QT_CONFIG(thread)`

Comment: In the `#if QT_CONFIG(thread)` branch some lines above maybe?

Comment: There is only one implementation of this fucntion in that file.

Comment: No, see [line 785](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/thread/qthread.cpp.html#785) - you're in the else branch

Comment: I know I'm in else branch, but there is only one implementation of this function.

Comment: I did't get what `239ff` mean, line 239 in this [file](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/thread/qthread.cpp?h=v5.12.6#n239) is comment.

Comment: Forgot to say - line [239 in qthread_unix.cpp](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/thread/qthread_unix.cpp.html#_ZN11QThreadData7currentEb)